# Image size before is in DOM

Tags: jquery

How can I get image size before I put it into the DOM?

```
var imgLoad = $("<img />");
$(imgLoad).attr("src", ImageGallery.ImagesList[index] + "?" + new Date().getTime());
$(imgLoad).unbind("load");
$(imgLoad).bind("load", function () {

   // Get image sizes
   alert(imgLoad.width()); // RETURN 0

});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `imgLoad[0].width` and `imgLoad[0].height` instead, or use `this` instead of `imgLoad`:

```
var imgLoad = $("<img />");
imgLoad.attr("src", ImageGallery.ImagesList[index] + "?" + new Date().getTime());
imgLoad.unbind("load");
imgLoad.bind("load", function () {

   // Get image sizes
   alert(this.width);

});
```

> **Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7twNk/**

This works because the browser populates the `height`/`width` properties of the element when it downloads the image.  jQuery, on the other hand, fetches the actual visible dimensions of the element — this will always be 0 when an element isn't displayed.

Note that you do not need to keep wrapping `imgLoad` with `$()` because it is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Note: if you want to get the natural width and height of an image that's already in the DOM, you can hide it (`display:none;`) and then call `img.width` as in the above example.  You'll probably need to set a timeout for 0ms to eliminate the race condition with updating the DOM vs. checking the width.

Comment: How come you unbind("load") before? It works just fine for me without that.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a new Image, .width will give you the native dimensions of the un-rendered image, whereas .width() is a jQuery method, and doesn't return a value until the image is inserted into the DOM.

In plain old JS;

```
var i = new Image()
i.src = 'blah.gif'
var h = i.height
var w = i.width
```

will return you a true value

Comment: Browsers don't stop JS execution while they fetch the image, so you need to wait until the `onload` event to retrieve the dimensions.