# What are jQuery angle bracket selector looking things, like $('<img/>')?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Sometimes I see constructs like [`$('<img/>')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124409/image-size-before-is-in-dom). How is `$('<img/>')` different from `$('img')` and where can I read more about this?

I tried looking at [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) but found nothing related to this format.

Comment: `$('<img/>')` is used to create a new element, `$('img')` is a dom selector, to get all the img elements from the dom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery function is overloaded to construct new jQuery elements when passed a string that looks like HTML. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with `<tag ... >`).
>   If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as
>   explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet,
>   jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.
>   Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these
>   elements.

Answer (score 5):

`$('<img/>')` **creates** an image, whereas `$('img')` selects all currently existing images.

Answer (score 3):

`$('<img />')` creates a new `<img />` element to be inserted to the DOM.

`$('img')` selects all existing `<img />` elements.

Generally, one would use `$('<img />')` to create elements in the DOM as follows:

```
var toAppend = $('<img />');
toAppend.appendTo($('#myDiv'));
```

Whereas you could use the `$('img');` selector to handle CSS (as an arbitrary example):

```
$('img').css('marginTop', 20);
```

The above will add a 20px margin to the top of each image in the DOM.